# Question on tables:

Tags: tables

New in TeX and i've done quite a few tables, but the recent one stumps me. can't quite get why the following text is not acceptable:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\textbf{Variable} & \textbf{Variable}& \textbf{Probability}\\
\                 & \textbf{(Weight)}&                     \\
\hline
$$Age (0-9)       & \beta\textsubscript{09}        & 0.000269072\\
Age (10-19)       & \beta\textsubscript{1019}      & 0.001297884\\
Age (20-29)       & \beta\textsubscript{2029}       & 0.007900182\\
Age (30-39)       & \beta\textsubscript{3039}      & 0.003849480\\
Age (40-49)       & \beta\textsubscript{4049}      & 0.006465789\\
Age (50-59)       & \beta\textsubscript{5059}      & 0.012566912\\
Age (60-69)       & \beta\textsubscript{6069}      & 0.015256684\\
Age (70-79)       & \beta\textsubscript{7079}      & 0.009464063\\
Age (80-89)       & \beta\textsubscript{8089}      & 0.009403302\\
Fever             & \beta\textsubscript{Fever}     & 0.150000000\\
Cough             & \beta\textsubscript{cough}     & 0.133333333\\
Sputum            & \beta\textsubscript{sputum}     & 0.038333333\\
Myalgia           & \beta\textsubscript{Myalgia}    & 0.048333333\\
Fatigue           & \beta\textsubscript{Fatigue}       & 0.038333333\\
Diarrhea          & \beta\textsubscript{Diarrhea}   & 0.008333333\\
Nausea            & \beta\textsubscript{nausea} & 0.006666667\\
Contact           & \beta\textsubscript{Contact}    & 0.094822396\\
Travel            & \beta\textsubscript{travel} & 0.094822396\\
Total             &   Total     & 0.679451492\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

[image]

I have attached the error here. Appreciate anyone's advise or comment.

Comment: Welcome! You cannot use `\beta` in text mode.

Comment: Wow, this community is great! :-) so sounds like im using some math function in text mode. thank you so much!

Comment: Yes. You could load `\usepackage{textgreek}` and then replace all `\beta` by `\textbeta`. If you remove `$$` before `Age (0-9)` the code should also work.

Comment: thank you. for a new Tex user below is pretty enough, but i'd go for your more elegant suggestion. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `\beta` in text mode. And you have two `$` signs which are not supposed there. The following cures the errors. It is not too pretty, though.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\textbf{Variable} & \textbf{Variable}& \textbf{Probability}\\
\                 & \textbf{(Weight)}&                     \\
\hline
Age (0-9)       & $\beta$\textsubscript{09}        & 0.000269072\\
Age (10-19)       & $\beta$\textsubscript{1019}      & 0.001297884\\
Age (20-29)       & $\beta$\textsubscript{2029}       & 0.007900182\\
Age (30-39)       & $\beta$\textsubscript{3039}      & 0.003849480\\
Age (40-49)       & $\beta$\textsubscript{4049}      & 0.006465789\\
Age (50-59)       & $\beta$\textsubscript{5059}      & 0.012566912\\
Age (60-69)       & $\beta$\textsubscript{6069}      & 0.015256684\\
Age (70-79)       & $\beta$\textsubscript{7079}      & 0.009464063\\
Age (80-89)       & $\beta$\textsubscript{8089}      & 0.009403302\\
Fever             & $\beta$\textsubscript{Fever}     & 0.150000000\\
Cough             & $\beta$\textsubscript{cough}     & 0.133333333\\
Sputum            & $\beta$\textsubscript{sputum}     & 0.038333333\\
Myalgia           & $\beta$\textsubscript{Myalgia}    & 0.048333333\\
Fatigue           & $\beta$\textsubscript{Fatigue}       & 0.038333333\\
Diarrhea          & $\beta$\textsubscript{Diarrhea}   & 0.008333333\\
Nausea            & $\beta$\textsubscript{nausea} & 0.006666667\\
Contact           & $\beta$\textsubscript{Contact}    & 0.094822396\\
Travel            & $\beta$\textsubscript{travel} & 0.094822396\\
Total             &   Total     & 0.679451492\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\textbf{Variable} & \textbf{Variable}& \textbf{Probability}\\
\                 & \textbf{(Weight)}&                     \\
\hline
Age (0-9)       & $\beta_\mathrm{09}$        & 0.000269072\\
Age (10-19)       & $\beta_\mathrm{1019}$      & 0.001297884\\
Age (20-29)       & $\beta_\mathrm{2029}$       & 0.007900182\\
Age (30-39)       & $\beta_\mathrm{3039}$      & 0.003849480\\
Age (40-49)       & $\beta_\mathrm{4049}$      & 0.006465789\\
Age (50-59)       & $\beta_\mathrm{5059}$      & 0.012566912\\
Age (60-69)       & $\beta_\mathrm{6069}$      & 0.015256684\\
Age (70-79)       & $\beta_\mathrm{7079}$      & 0.009464063\\
Age (80-89)       & $\beta_\mathrm{8089}$      & 0.009403302\\
Fever             & $\beta_\mathrm{Fever}$     & 0.150000000\\
Cough             & $\beta_\mathrm{cough}$     & 0.133333333\\
Sputum            & $\beta_\mathrm{sputum}$     & 0.038333333\\
Myalgia           & $\beta_\mathrm{Myalgia}$    & 0.048333333\\
Fatigue           & $\beta_\mathrm{Fatigue}$       & 0.038333333\\
Diarrhea          & $\beta_\mathrm{Diarrhea}$   & 0.008333333\\
Nausea            & $\beta_\mathrm{nausea}$ & 0.006666667\\
Contact           & $\beta_\mathrm{Contact}$    & 0.094822396\\
Travel            & $\beta_\mathrm{travel}$ & 0.094822396\\
Total             &   Total     & 0.679451492\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: LuaTeX does allow `\beta` in text mode. ;)

Comment: @user125730 If that's the case then the error messages shown in the post strongly suggest that the OP is not using `lualatex`.

Comment: Only for completeness. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `\beta` in text mode.

I suggest to introduce a personal command for this, namely `\tbeta`

```
\newcommand{\tbeta}[1]{\ensuremath{\beta_{\textup{#1}}}}
```

(yes, this is a place where `\ensuremath` is good). I also removed the vertical rules, that only hinder the readability, and added a couple of horizontal rules to separate the various parts of the table.

The subscripts have been normalized to lowercase. Either all with uppercase initial or none.

For number ranges, an en-dash `--` is preferable to a hyphen.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,booktabs,siunitx}

\sisetup{group-digits=integer}

\newcommand{\tbeta}[1]{\ensuremath{\beta_{\textup{#1}}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering

\begin{tabular}{lcS[table-format=1.9]}
\toprule
\textbf{Variable} & \textbf{Variable} & {\textbf{Probability}}\\
                  & \textbf{(Weight)} &                       \\
\midrule
Age (0--9)   & \tbeta{09}       & 0.000269072\\
Age (10--19) & \tbeta{1019}     & 0.001297884\\
Age (20--29) & \tbeta{2029}     & 0.007900182\\
Age (30--39) & \tbeta{3039}     & 0.003849480\\
Age (40--49) & \tbeta{4049}     & 0.006465789\\
Age (50--59) & \tbeta{5059}     & 0.012566912\\
Age (60--69) & \tbeta{6069}     & 0.015256684\\
Age (70--79) & \tbeta{7079}     & 0.009464063\\
Age (80--89) & \tbeta{8089}     & 0.009403302\\
\midrule
Fever        & \tbeta{fever}    & 0.150000000\\
Cough        & \tbeta{cough}    & 0.133333333\\
Sputum       & \tbeta{sputum}   & 0.038333333\\
Myalgia      & \tbeta{myalgia}  & 0.048333333\\
Fatigue      & \tbeta{fatigue}  & 0.038333333\\
Diarrhea     & \tbeta{diarrhea} & 0.008333333\\
Nausea       & \tbeta{nausea}   & 0.006666667\\
Contact      & \tbeta{contact}  & 0.094822396\\
Travel       & \tbeta{travel}   & 0.094822396\\
\midrule
Total        & Total            & 0.679451492\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it really necessary to point out that one cannot use `\beta` in text mode as if this has not already been pointed out?